# Creating an interactive full motion video game using HTML5

Tags: iphone, android, ios, html

The basic parts of this full motion video game is:

- The user is shown a video clip which either plays to the end or can be skipped. A clip could be something like a character talking or of a location. Some of the clips might loop until the user clicks something e.g. the clip might show birds flying in the park.
- The user is presented with several choices that are overlaid over the video clip at some point where the choices are things like "1. go to the park" or "2. ask the man about the park".
- Each choice is linked with another video clip and another set of choices e.g. if the user picks option 2, they are shown a video of the man responding and can then follow up with more questions.
- I'd like the above to look seamless and presentable. For example, video clips and text options should fade in and out and I'd like the  page to be fullscreen.

Would it be possible to do the above in HTML5 while supporting most desktop and mobile browsers? Would some other language be more appropriate? I'd rather not use Flash, primarily because then I cannot easily support iOS.

From doing some research, the above seems easily possible in all modern browsers on desktop machines with the caveat that there doesn't appear to be any reliable way to make an HTML5 page go full screen, unlike Flash. The iOS situation looks grim: as far as I know video clips will only play once the user has clicked on the clip and I'm not sure if I can overlay buttons on these. I've also read that the video tag can be buggy on Android.

Can anyone comment on what approach I can use for addressing these issues?

Edit:
More info:

- I have no constraints about it being server or client hosted.
- I know I can't realistically get this to work on every browser out there so I'm really asking: without having to write several ports of the game, what approach can I use to target a sizeable  audience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can HTML 5 embed video? Certainly. Will it work on most desktop and mobile browsers? Well, define 'most'. If we're talking pure numbers, then no. Lots of the planet still using IE <8 on the desktop and Symbian on the Nokias.

The bigger issue, IMHO, is that video on a mobile device is typically handled by the device. I'm not sure you can over-ride that. For instance, on an iPhone, if I click an embedded video, it pops it out as it's own full-screen video. You'd have to experiment and see if you have any control over that.

Finally, is this a server hosted game? If so, grabbing a bunch of videos over a cell network may not be the idea user experience.

Comment: And in some parts of the world, operators fleece customers on data fees, never mind the bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've added some more info to the end of my question. Regarding bandwidth, I'm not sure there's much I can do here without asking the user to download all the video clips before playing the game.

Comment: if the goal is to try to have one codebase, and there is potential you want this to perhaps be turned into an app, then HTML5 is definitely the way to go. Most modern browsers will be OK with it and via things like PhoneGap, you can fairly easily get it into different mobile OS app forms. Again, though, I think your bigger issue is user experience...make sure the mobile devices handle the video the way you want and that the game is feasible over a cell network's throughput.

Comment: Hmm, according to this, HTML5 video playing is only supported by about 50% of browsers that account for web page visits: http://www.streaminglearningcenter.com/blogs/less-than-1-of-websites-fully-html5-compatible.html

Comment: Yes, again, it really depends on the specifics of who you are trying to target.